# git for Windows: can't seem to avoid CR/LF diff to patch apply errors

Tags: windows, git, diff, apply

So I'm running git in Windows with a repo that runs on *nix, where git checks out Windows-style newlines (line ending CRLF) but commits *nix-style (LF), however I can't get a diff/apply to work without some fatal snag no matter what I've tried.

For example, I run a diff to a file from one commit to another like:

`git diff commit1 commit2 > patch.diff`

But when I run `git apply patch.diff`, I get errors like:

`trailing whitespace
patch failed
patch does not apply`

I've tried setting `git config --global core.autocrlf true`, tried `git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace patch.diff`, and `git config --global core.whitespace cr-at-eol`, and even if it works, the apply shows that almost every line of code was changed just because of the newlines.

If I check the applied patch in something like Git GUI or WinMerge, it shows the proper changes just because they ignore newline changes, but either the diff or apply command is considering the newline differences, and everything I've found on the web to try just doesn't end up with a proper result.

I found something about `git rm --cached -r .` but it requires committing all files with "fixed" newlines... which isn't feasible for our project (and shouldn't be necessary).

Am I just not running the right combination or commands and options or what am I supposed to do?

Comment: What shell are you using when you run these git commands? You might want to check the diff file with `cat --show-all` and see just what whitespace is included in the file. Powershell for instance causes unicode files to be created following redirection

Comment: GIt 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017) should improve this: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46044063/6309

Comment: I think we can close this good question as a duplicate now [how to avoid git-apply changing line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308625/how-to-avoid-git-apply-changing-line-endings)

Answer (score 0):

This question is not a duplicate of "how to avoid git-apply changing line endings". That question deals with the patch applying correctly, whereas this one deals with the patch not applying at all. However, I think it is a duplicate of [How to use patches created in windows (with CRLF) in linux?I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076688/how-to-use-patches-created-in-windows-with-crlf-in-linuxi).

I had this issue as well. In my case, the root cause was that the files had a BOM (byte order mark), whereas the patch didn't.

The solution in my case was to remove the BOM from the target file by passing it thru `dos2unix` (`--remove-bom`, but it's the default behaviour anyway) first. You can then invoke `unix2dos` (with `--add-bom`) if you like.

Rather than manually processing each target file, you may run the following:

```bash
git apply my_patch.diff --numstat --no-apply | cut -f 3- | xargs dos2unix --remove-bom
git apply my_patch.diff 
git apply my_patch.diff --numstat --no-apply | cut -f 3- | xargs unix2dos --add-bom
```